# How to remove borders under play button and logo img in CSS?

Tags: css, border

How to remove borders under play button and around logo img in CSS?
How to remove borders under play button and around logo img in CSS?
How to remove borders under play button and around logo img in CSS?
How to remove borders under play button and around logo img in CSS?
How to remove borders under play button and around logo img in CSS?

[image: 1]

```css
.fullscreen {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                background: no-repeat url('https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2019/10/switzerland-in-pictures-most-beautiful-places-matterhorn.jpg') center / cover;
            }
            .line_horiz {
                position: absolute;
                width: 3px;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
                top: 0;
                left: 50%;
            }
            .line_vert {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                height: 3px;
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
                top: 20%;
                left: 0;
            }
            .logo-img {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border: 3px solid #ffffff;
                background: #ffffff;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                top: 20%;
                left: 50%;
                z-index: 1;
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .btn {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border: 3px solid #ffffff;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                z-index: 1;
            }
            .btn::after {
                content: '';
                display: block;
                width: 60px;
                height: 60px;
                background: #ffffff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
            <span class="line_vert"></span>
            <span class="line_horiz"></span>
            <div class="logo-img">Logo img</div>
            <div class="btn"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code, both HTML and CSS - there is no way we can help sensibly withouth knowing how those lines are drawn and what the HTML structure is.

Comment: i've added code you asked for

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. As the lines are part of the styling rather than the content I'd suggest making them part of the background e.g. with linear gradients. I'll put up a snippet shortly to demonstrate.

Comment: ok. I'll be waiting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the horizontal and vertical lines are styling rather than informational content one suggestion is to remove them from the body of the HTML and instead create them using linear gradients on the background of the fullscreen element. That way they don't for example get looked at by screen readers. Also, using linear gradients means we can have 'gaps' in the lines where we want them.

This snippet just does the calculation of the gap for the btn element as the logo element has background white so it doesn't matter that the 'line' goes right across. If this changes then put in a linear gradient with gap calculations in a similar way to that done for the btn.

Note, box-sizing with content has been used and explicitly stated (so borders are included in the calculations and padding is set to zero) in case it has been altered elsewhere in the code.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.fullscreen {
  /* set up some variables to make it easier to change things later if you want to */
  --logoMid: calc(20% - var(--borderW));
  --btnW: 100px;
  --btnMid: 50%;
  /* position from the top to the middle of the btn */
  --borderW: 3px;
  --btnTop: calc(var(--btnMid) - (var(--btnW) / 2) - (var(--borderW) / 2));
  /* actual position of top of btn element */
  --btnBottom: calc(var(--btnTop) + var(--btnW) + var(--borderW));
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white 0%, white var(--btnTop), transparent var(--btnTop), transparent var(--btnBottom), white var(--btnBottom), white 100%), linear-gradient(to right, white 0, white 100%), url('https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2019/10/switzerland-in-pictures-most-beautiful-places-matterhorn.jpg');
  background-size: var(--borderW) 100%, 100% var(--borderW), cover;
  background-position: calc(var(--btnMid) - (var(--borderW) / 2)) 0, 0 var(--logoMid), center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.logo-img {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.btn {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.btn::after {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
  <div class="logo-img">Logo img</div>
  <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

Note: run the snippet in full screen as there won't be enough room to show the gap between the logo and btn on the small snippet viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, Its not perfect, but it will give you a good starting points.

I have changes your HTML structure, by removing the divs that create the lines, Instead, I have used pseudo selectors to draw the lines.

Note that, you will have to tweak some of these numbers to properly fit your content.

**Please run the example in full screen mode**

```css
.fullscreen {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: no-repeat url("https://www.planetware.com/wpimages/2019/10/switzerland-in-pictures-most-beautiful-places-matterhorn.jpg") center/cover;
}

.logo-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.logo-img:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: calc(50vw - 90px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  left: 130px;
  display: block;
}

.logo-img:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: calc(50vw - 90px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  top: 50%;
  right: 130px;
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn .inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

.btn:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 3px;
  height: calc(50vh - 48px);
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 3px;
  top: calc(-50vh + 220px);
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullscreen">
  <div class="logo-img">Logo img</div>
  <div class="btn">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```